# How to remove the option to boot from Ubuntu in the Windows Boot loader?

Tags: wubi

An year and a half ago, I installed Ubuntu on my computer using Wubi. After a while I decided to install Ubuntu on a separate partition. So I uninstalled the Ubuntu using Wubi, and installed Ubuntu on a separate partition by booting from the Ubuntu ISO.

Though Wubi uninstalled Ubuntu from my Windows partition it did not remove the option in the boot menu. So now when I boot, the grub menu has option for Windows and Ubuntu, but if I choose Windows from the menu, I again get two options - Windows and Ubuntu, this time from the Windows boot loader. If I choose Ubuntu, it just shows and error asks to go back.

So how do I remove the option?

EDIT:  I have tried to use bcdedit but it did not help.
If I run bcdedit on the command prompt, this is the output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=V:
path                    \bootmgr
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
default                 {e58e9c4c-dc5b-11e1-be69-bb3b6bb64ef4}
displayorder            {e58e9c4c-dc5b-11e1-be69-bb3b6bb64ef4}
bootsequence            {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 3

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {e58e9c4c-dc5b-11e1-be69-bb3b6bb64ef4}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7 Ultimate (recovered) 
locale                  en-US
recoverysequence        {e58e9c4d-dc5b-11e1-be69-bb3b6bb64ef4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
```

According to this I should only have one entry which should be named `Windows 7 Ultimate (recovered)` but instead when I boot I have two entries, one named Windows 7 and the other named Ubuntu. I couldn't find any answer by googling.

I also tried to set the timeout to 0, but again for no help, the boot screen still waits three seconds before selecting the default option.

Answer (score 2):

Start menu > type '`msconfig`' > within the 'boot' tab, remove the entry from there.

Comment: There is no entry there.